# Как наполнять UICollectionView контентом из двух источников

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Дело в том, что нужно отображать контент из двух источников в моем collectionview. Для этого я создал две custom cell. Один источник - статический, должен отображаться всегда, второй - динамический, юзер может загружать до 20 фото, и они должны отображаться до статического контента.
[image: UICollectionViewExample]
              Черные ячейки - загруженный контент, до 20 штук. Пока удалось реализовать только одно фото, но стало очевидно что я совсем не в том направлении иду.

images - загруженные юзером изображения.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if images.isEmpty && indexPath.row == 0  { // отрисовывает на первом месте ПлюсКлетку и наполняет плюсом если нет загрузок
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("PlusCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PlusCollectionViewCell
        let image : UIImage = UIImage(named: "plusimage")!
        cell.PlusImage.image = image
        return cell
    }
    if images.isEmpty == false && indexPath.row == 0 {//отрисовывает collectionview с загруженным контентом после выбора фото
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("PlusCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PlusCollectionViewCell
        cell.data = self.images[indexPath.row]
        return cell

    }
    else { //отрисовываем статический контент
                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ImageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ContentCollectionViewCell
        cell.data = imgdatas[indexPath.row - 1]
        return cell
    }

}
```

Понимаю что код выглядит ужасно, но есть как есть.
Как это правильно реализовать? Что нужно использовать?

Comment: ну у вас 3 статических, и до 20 динамических. статические всегда должны быть в конце. а вопрос в чем?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что ну хочется же рашн

Comment: Прошу прощения, почему-то решил что пишу в англоязычную версию. Вопрос отредактировал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 1. Сделайте 2 секции и первую заполняйте динамическим контентом, вторую статическим.

Вариант 2. Заполняйте модель данными так, чтобы статический контент всегда был в конце и отображайте.

Comment: Подскажите, где почитать про каждый из вариантов?

Comment: @Ruslan , даже не подскажу именно хороший материал. Когда добрался до `UICollectionView` просто делал по аналогии с `UITableView`. Вот, к примеру, первое что дал гугл: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBStfJCaQFE . По 2 - в Ваш `imgdatas` складывайте картинки так чтобы статические были в конце массива и отображайте.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, попытался реализовать это с помощью секций, но столкнулся со следующей проблемой: первая секция, которая наполняется контентом всегда занимает целую строку, независимо от того, сколько фото загружено. Примерно так: http://itmag.es/P6cg Не смог найти решения, все говорят только об отступах между клетками, но не секциями. Есть идеи как это исправить?

Comment: Решение с imgdatas не могу реализовать по причине того, что один контент берется из телефона, а другой, который отображается статично, из сети.

Comment: @Ruslan покажите как Вы получаете данные и заполняете коллекцию

Comment: Вот: http://pastebin.com/hkduBiw8

Comment: спасибо за наводку, удалось реализовать добавление фото в imgdatas